# Better way to make dictionary of counts from a QuerySet based on a field in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a queryset of objects that could have any text value in their field and I would like a dictionary of the counts of the values in that field. For example:

I have a Test Drives Object which has a foreign key to vehicle, which has a make (Char field). I would like to know how many Test Drives each make had. I have actually solved it already, but I wonder if there is a better way using Django's inbuilt functionality.

My existing, working solution:

```
customer_test_drives_makes = customer_test_drives.values_list('vehicle__make', flat=True).order_by('vehicle__make').distinct()
customer_test_drives_makes_dictionary = {}
for make in customer_test_drives_makes :
    customer_test_drives_makes_dictionary[make] = customer_test_drives.filter(vehicle__make=make).count()
print(customer_test_drives_makes_dictionary)
```

This prints:`{'BMW': 1, 'Honda': 1, 'Hyundai': 1, 'Mazda': 2}` Which is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruddra's answer got me most of the way, but I had to make the values distinct. Here are the final solutions:

Pre-existing way:

```
queryset_makes = queryset.values_list('vehicle__make', flat=True).order_by('vehicle__make').distinct()
queryset_makes_dictionairy = {}
for make in queryset_makes :
    queryset_makes_dictionairy[make] = queryset.filter(vehicle__make=make).count()

print(queryset_makes_dictionairy)
```

Result:

```
{'BMW': 1, 'Honda': 4, 'Hyundai': 1, 'Mazda': 2, 'Mitsubishi': 1, 'Nissan': 2}
```

**------------**

Updated Way:

`print(queryset.values('vehicle__make').order_by('vehicle__make').distinct().annotate(count=Count('vehicle__make')))`

Result:

```
<QuerySet [{'vehicle__make': 'BMW', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Honda', 'count': 4}, {'vehicle__make': 'Hyundai', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Mazda', 'count': 2}, {'vehicle__make': 'Mitsubishi', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Nissan', 'count': 2}]>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is. Try group by using [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count

customer_test_drives.values('vehicle__make').annotate(count=Count('vehicle__make')).values()
```

Another example: Suppose your model looks like this:

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Then you can run this queryset as well:

```
Vehicle.objects.annotate(car_count=Count('cars'))
```

Comment: This gets me close, but not quite. This gives me a QuerySet of vehicle__make where all the counts are 1: 
    <QuerySet [{'vehicle__make': 'Mazda', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'BMW', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Mazda', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Hyundai', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Honda', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Honda', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Nissan', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Honda', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Honda', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Nissan', 'count': 1}, {'vehicle__make': 'Mitsubishi', 'count': 1}]>

Comment: I had to make the values distinct. Got it now, thats for your help